# How to find the posterior distribution given data and prior distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, means, gamma-distribution

Suppose that following conditions are true:

$$ X\mid\Theta=\theta\sim N(0,\theta) $$

$$ \Theta\sim InvGamma(2,1) $$

We need to find a posterior distribution: $$ f\left(\Theta\mid X\right) $$ given the data $$ X=-0.45,-3.92,-5.85,2.83,0.3 $$

And find:

$$ E\left\lbrack\Theta\mid X\right\rbrack,Var\left\lbrack\Theta\mid X\right\rbrack $$

First of all i'd like to find a function for the posterior distribution so i'll use this relationship:

$$ f\left(\Theta\mid X\right)\propto f\left(X\mid\Theta\right)\cdot f\left(\Theta\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2\theta^{}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(2\right)}\theta^{-3}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right) $$

$$ =\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\theta\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{n\overline{x}}{2\theta^{}}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{1}\theta^{-3}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\propto\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\theta\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{n\overline{x}}{2\theta^{}}\right)\cdot\theta^{-3} $$

However I am not sure what to do here. The problems that I have are:

1. How do I find a distribution that matches this function? My reasoning for this is that if I do find one, I can find the expected value and variance for it quite easily.
2. I am not sure what to do with the mean X even if I do find one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expression is slightly off, the gaussian likelihood should instead be:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \theta}} \exp \left (-\frac{X_i^2}{2\theta} \right ) 
\stackrel{\theta}{\propto} \theta^{-n/2}  \exp \left (-\frac{1}{2 \theta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \right ) 
= \theta^{-n/2}  \exp \left (-\frac{n \overline{X^2}}{2 \theta}\right ) 
$$

Therefore, the posterior is proportional to:
$$
f(\theta|X)
\stackrel{\theta}{\propto}
\theta^{-n/2}  \exp \left (-\frac{n \overline{X^2}}{2 \theta}\right )
\theta^{-3} 
=\theta^{-(3+n/2)}  \exp \left (-\frac{n \overline{X^2}}{2 \theta}\right )
=\theta^{-{(2+n/2)}-1}  
\exp \left (-\frac{(n \overline{X^2}/2)}{\theta}\right )
$$

The last equality is written in this form to hint at the following important observation: by inspection, this looks much like the density of an inverse-Gamma distributed random variable. Recall that for $Y \sim \text{Inverse-Gamma}(a,b)$,
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)} y^{-a-1} \exp(-b/y)
$$
and so we can take $a = 2+n/2$ and $b = \frac{n }{2}\overline{X^2}$, i.e. we have shown that
$$
\theta|X \sim \text{Inverse-Gamma} \left (
2+\frac{n}{2},  \frac{n }{2}\overline{X^2}
\right )
$$
and in your specific case,  $\frac{n }{2}\overline{X^2} = \frac{5}{2} \times  11.57806 = 28.94515$, so

$$
\theta|X \sim \text{Inverse-Gamma} \left (
4.5,  28.94515
\right ).
$$

From here you can use standard results about the inverse gamma to compute the posterior mean and posterior variance. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) page, we have

$$
E[\theta|X] = \frac{b}{a-1} = \frac{28.94515} {3.5} = 8.270043
$$
and
$$
\text{Var}(\theta|X) = \frac{b^2}{(a-1)^2(a-2)}
$$